# Difference Between using Contact Data vs Event Data for same DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, journeybuilder, entry-criteria

Need to understand the difference in results If I use Event Data vs using Contact Data for the same Data Extension in a Source Entry Event or in a Decision Split.

**Example**

I have a DE named Alert where-in I am using this condition for Source Entry or Decision Split

```
AlertCategory Equal INQUIRY OR AlertCategory Equal NEW_ACCOUNT 
OR AlertCategory Equal NEW_ADDRESS
```

For making this condition, I use

```
Event Data -> AlertCategory for INQUIRY and NEW_ACCOUNT
```

But for NEW_ADDRESS I use,

`Contact Data -> ALert DE -> AlertCategory.`

Note that in both the above Cases, the Data Extension is the same one.

Does it make any difference in results when:

```
1. Used for Entry Source Condition

2. Used for Decision Split.
```

Comment: I am facing another problem that I am not getting the Entry Source DE in Contact Data, while all other DEs are appearing in Contact Data. This has not happened before for us. Any pointers ? Pls advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the difference between Event data and contact data in the below link:

https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/journey_builder/using_event_data/

In a nutshell, in the entry source condition, event data and contact data will not make much a difference unless your data extension is updated frequently

In Decision split, you need to use event data if you want to compare the attributes as they were in when they registered a journey and Contact data if you want to compare the attributes as the evaluation is done.

For e.g. if you are on a registration journey and sending mails only if registration flag (that is updated from external system) is false, then you need to use contact data as it would compare the latest status of registration.

Comment: Thank You Ganesh. I am facing another problem that I am not getting the Entry Source DE in Contact Data, while all other DEs are appearing in Contact Data. This has not happened before for us. Any pointers ?

Comment: Check the post: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/141409/contact-data-not-working-in-descision-split-activty-in-journey-builder. We had a issue with contact data earlier. might be salesforce would have restricted DE after this issue

Comment: My Issue got solved after adding the DE to contact attributes.
Thanks :)