# Journey Builder Engagement Split Open

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I configured a Journey Builder where a contact can re-entry anytime.
This journey has an email and an engagement split, that verifies if the contact opens the email or not.

I noticed that if the contact opened the email the first time he receveid it, then also the next times the engagement split counted/treated the email as an open. Therefore the contact always procedeed down this decisions' "Yes" branch.

Do you notice the same behaviour? Any suggestion/way to make Journey Builder, treat opens differently?

Comment: What kind of entry source do you use? I encountered similar behavior for normal decision splits when using api triggered and sales/service cloud triggered entry events. You can find these possibly related questions here: [sales/service cloud entry event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/172931/36218), [api entry event](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/150276/36218)

Comment: could you elaborate on requirements? (what is the use case for sending the same email, multiple times, and then "caring" about whether they open or not? what happens if they open it?)

Comment: I just tested this and am experiencing the same issue. For me a usual use case where this is necessary is sending offers for products in the same category to customers. The follow-up would be different if one offer hasn't been opened for example.

Comment: I guess the problem is the same as for the decision splits I posted in my first comment. The only id that is used to evaluate the split is the contact-id so for multiple entries this leads to incorrect results. I already contacted a Sr. Technical Product Manager at Salesforce Marketing Cloud who should be able to provide further information. If he cannot provide a better/easier solution than the one I came up with, I'll soon provide a workaround on my [github-account](https://github.com/mslabina) which involves quite some development and hosting effort and changes to the emails used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just received feedback from salesforce marketing cloud technical support and this is a known issue.

**Currently scheduled release for this functionality:** August '17 Release (wich will occur on 25th August according to [Salesforce Marketing Cloud 2017 Release Schedule](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/release_notes/salesforce_marketing_cloud_2017_release_schedule/))

**Answer of the technical support team:**

> Currently we have plans to amend this functionality you've reported as we recognise this is a gap inside the Marketing Cloud and Journey Builder application.
>
> **Unfortunately this is classified as 'working as designed'** and the project to improve this isn't marked as a Bug within the system, but we do have this in a list of to-do for future JB development.
>
> Currently it looks like **we're working to improve this for our August Release** but this is just a schedule at present, it's not a definitive so it could get pushed back.

**Possible workaround:**

The possible workaround I can think of involves some development and hosting effort, but seems to be the only option until the changes to journey builder are released. Some work of another workaround I built can be reused to reduce the development effort as much as possible. These are the steps needed to set up the workaround I'd like to propose:

1. Create and host a custom tracking site/pixel or use an existing service you can query.
2. Create and host a custom split activity (could be based on my [Salesforce Marketing Cloud - Service Cloud Custom Split Activity](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit))

   - Adapt input arguments to include an id unique to the very send you want to track (needs to be information available in the journey and added as parameter to the tracking pixel in the email)
   - Instead of querying Service Cloud, check the result of your tracking site/pixel
3. Use the custom split activity instead of the engagement split

Comment: @robertc You are welcome! As from the feedback of salesforce my answer is correct, so please accept my answer so all users can see this is the solution to your question. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry @Markus, i have another question because i am testing if it is possible to create these data extensions (https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/query_activity/) in order to retrieve data (bounces more specifically). My aim is to check after about 5 hours from the email sending if the email address has bounced or not. 
I should link bounces DE into contact builder and create a decision split into the jounery. Have you ever tested it?

Comment: No I haven't, but as evaluation currently only works using the subscriber key I guess you will run into the same problem and will need a custom split until path selection feature is released. However to be sure, I recommend asking a separate question so other users who possibly tried something similar can find your question more easily.